# Do familiars moving out of enemy reach provoke opportunity attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, opportunity-attack, familiars

Setup: You are a 3rd-level Warlock with Pact of the Chain. Your chosen familiar is a Pseudodragon. A combat encounter ensues, and it is eventually your familiar's turn. You have it use the Help action to assist an ally, who is the next in the turn order. Turns then proceed as normal, and it is eventually your familiar's turn again. The enemy it Helped against is still right next to it, and you decide to have the familiar move away from it.

Since your familiar is now attempting to move out of range of an enemy without Disengaging, does this trigger an opportunity attack towards it from that enemy?

Comment: [Related] [Can a familiar use its reaction to attack someone leaving his reach?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/90510)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Yes

All creatures provoke opportunity attacks in that way unless a feature or certain situation prevents it. For example, owls have the Flyby feature which explicitly prevents them from provoking opportunity attacks when they move from an enemy's reach.

Answer (score 10):

Yes. Familiars are creatures, and any enemy (assuming it is not in some way incapacitated) can choose to make an opportunity attack against it if the enemy leaves its melee attack range and has a reaction to spend doing so.